# WiX Multiple Instances - Remove Custom Resources on uninstall of last Instance

Tags: wix, certificate, multiple-instances

I am creating a Multi-Instance MSI for my product using WiX.

The `MultiInstance="yes"` attribute solves the problem of managing all supported resources (like files, registry values, windows services etc.) in a multi-instance environment.

However, I don't know how to approach the same issue with non-built-in types of resources (like Certificates). There is no problem with creating a separate Certificate on each instance Install and deleting it on every instance Uninstall...

But what if I need a shared Certificate? 
Meaning that the first installed instance will create it and the last removed will delete it (equivalent to a Component with `MultiInstance="no"`)

I am using the method described here to implement multiple instances for my MSI:

```
http://ysdevlog.blogspot.co.il/2011/08/revisited-multiple-instance.html
```

In short, every instance "registers" itself in a predefined Registry location and so I can be aware of the currently installed instances:

```
<Component Id="RegistryComponent" Guid="{GUIDGOES-HERE-45e5-ABFD-07E5CC4D7BC9}" MultiInstance="yes">
      <RegistryKey Id="MainRegKey" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MultiInstanceTest\[ProductCode]">
         <RegistryValue Id="MainRegValue" Name="InstanceId" Value="[INSTANCEID]" Type="string" />
         <RegistryValue Id="InstallPathValue" Name="Location" Value="[ProductNameFolder]" Type="string" />
         <RegistryValue Id="ProductCodeValue" Name="ProductCode" Value="[ProductCode]" Type="string" />
         <RegistryValue Id="ProductNameValue" Name="ProductName" Value="[ProductName]" Type="string" />
         <RegistryValue Id="ProductVersionValue" Name="ProductVersion" Value="[ProductVersion]" Type="string" />
      </RegistryKey>
   </Component>
```

This helps me manage installation and removal of instances using a small external program that basically reads this Registry location and shoots `msiexec` commands.

I need to be able to determine if it's the last instance in order to delete any custom shared resource (eg. a Certificate).
Using `RegistrySearch` doesn't help because it runs before the Registry entries are removed - so it will always find the keys/values still intact.

How can I determine if the current Uninstall is removing the last instance?